# Svelte multiple dates datepicker

Tags: javascript, svelte

Right now I have a date picker like such:

```
<input type="date" bind:value={date} on:select={newDateSelected} on:change={newDateSelected}>
```

but I want to be able to pick multiple dates like this example for DatePicker (the multiple tab part): http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html. However, this example (and plenty other ones I've seen online) use jQuery, which I don't really want to incorporate (I also heard it's not the best idea to incorporate it but I'm not too sure on that part.

Is there a way I can choose multiple dates in native js or svelte?

Comment: Do you want the exact experience as http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html where you can select and deselect from the calendar? Because you could use regular svelte code to implement this but in html?

Comment: You could use [svelty-picker](https://github.com/mskocik/svelty-picker) or [svelte-flatpickrr](https://github.com/jacobmischka/svelte-flatpickr). Flatpickr may not be working with the newest version of sveltekit but they both work pretty well.